# Tokenization: Refer to particular tokens after read multiple .dat files

Tags: c++

I've used the code below to read multiple .dat files into 2D vectors and print out tokens values. However, I need to know if all tokens values will be stored in the memory after the compilation completes, and how can I refer to a certain element like `token[3][27]` as an example for further processing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); ++i) {
        cout << "file name: " << files[i] << endl;

        fin.open(files[i].c_str());
        if (!fin.is_open()) {
            cout<<"error"<<endl;
        }


        std::vector<vector<string>> tokens;

        int current_line = 0;
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(fin, line))
        {

            cout<<"line number: "<<current_line<<endl;
            // Create an empty vector for this line
            tokens.push_back(vector<string>());

            //copy line into is 
            std::istringstream is(line);
            std::string token;
            int n = 0;

            //parsing
            while (getline(is, token, DELIMITER))
            {
                tokens[current_line].push_back(token);
                cout<<"token["<<current_line<<"]["<<n<<"] = " << token <<endl; 
                n++;
            }
            cout<<"\n";
            current_line++;
        }
        fin.clear();
        fin.close();

    }
```

Do I need to create 2D vector for each file? can that be achieved during the runtime in C++ ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your 2D vector further you need to declare it outside the `for` loop. The way you did it you create a local variable which is destroyed each and every loop iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); ++i) {
    std::vector<vector<string>> tokens(i);
}
tokens[0][0]; // you can't do it here: variable tokens not declared in this scope
```

Of course you can use your `tokens` container right after the while loop, addressing certain token just the way you mentioned it.

To use tokens outside the for loop you can either make a 3D vector holding files,lines,tokens, or make this a function which returns 2D vector for certain file, and then you can process it.